# how to get files names in current app directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to apply the following code to get all ASPX pages in the app directory and it returns with errors. However, I have a problem with many phases. And It can be solved if I know how to get files names in the current directory using multiple conditions.

1. Request.ApplicationPath doesn't come back with ASPX pages
2. I need all ASPX pages where not in the Admin folder
3. I need names for display on ListBox1 and directories for ListBox1 values

**C#**

```
string dir = Request.ApplicationPath;
string[] files = new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetFiles("*.aspx", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(o => o.Name).ToArray();
//.Where(s => s.notIntheFolder("Admin"));


ListBox1.DataSource = files;
ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put a break point and see what you get for dir , then hard code that into the "dir" in
new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetFiles(... and see what is going on

Comment: @Srinika, I was onboard about setting a break-point and seeing what dir was pointing to but I don't understand "then hard code that into the "dir" in new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetFiles(."  This makes no sense to me.

Comment: `Request.ApplicationPath` returns the *virtual application path* not the path in the server's file systen.

Comment: Señor CMasMas-Reinstate Monica, 
ie. say if you get "/" as dir, then check by putting new DirectoryInfo("/")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following change

```
string dir = Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath);
```

For the ASPX pages where not in the Admin folder, Use LINQ

```
    string dir = Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath);

    // which will consider all directories (not excluding any)  
    string[] files = new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetFiles("*.aspx", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(o => o.Name).ToArray();

    // To get files under folders except "Admin

    // be careful about the case Word Admin - (ie. The Directory name has to be exactly same to avoid, otherwise convert both to lower case and compare) 
    var dirs = new DirectoryInfo(dir).GetDirectories().Where(q => q.Name != "Admin");

    List<string> filesInDirs = new List<string>();
    foreach (var dirName in dirs)
    {
        filesInDirs.AddRange(new DirectoryInfo(dirName.FullName).GetFiles("*.aspx", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Select(o => o.Name));
    }
```

Comment: would you please give me how to apply LINQ to do this?